# iOS 7 - Get Data/Info from a Website

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store-connect

I have written a Star Trek style LCARS clock app for myself for the iPad. It works quite well, but I would like to incorporate something to indicate whether or not iTunes Connect Sales Reports have been published. I was thinking of having a label that says "iTC" and changing the  text color depending on the status. My problem is that I do not know how to get the information automatically from the internet. I have been using the following site to check using a web browser: http://appfigures.com/itcstatus. But I want to implement this in my clock app, so that it will check automatically and display the status without me having to go to the website on a web browser. I was wondering whether I could simply copy the CSS code of the above website that specifies the color of the strip in the center of the screen and use that as the label color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an NSURLConnection like this:

```
NSData *rawHtml = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```